# Not able to launch the Openstack instance from Terraform

Tags: openstack, terraform

I am trying to create an OpenStack instance using Terraform but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* openstack_compute_instance_v2.basic: Error creating OpenStack server: Invalid
request due to incorrect syntax or missing required parameters.

Terraform does not automatically rollback in the face of errors.
Instead, your Terraform state file has been partially updated with
```

but the same Terraform code does successfully create the security group, key pair and volume in my OpenStack account

Here is my Terraform code:

```
provider "openstack" {
  user_name = "admin"
  tenant_name = "admin"
  password  = "admin"
  auth_url  = "http://my_IP():5000/v2.0"
}
resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v1" "myvol" {
  name = "myvol"
  size = 1
}
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "basic" {
  name = "basic"
  image_id = "8ce1c922-ad0-81a3-823ea1b0af9b"
  flavor_id = "2"
  key_pair = "tf-keypair-1"
  security_groups = ["default"]

  metadata {
    this = "that"
  }

  network {
    name = "8b510300-610a--9cc3-6e76e33395b4"
  }
  volume {
    volume_id = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v1.myvol.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you exported the `OS_REGION_NAME` name environment variable correctly?

Answer (score 9):

This message was quite hard to debug up until recently. In [version 0.8.8 of Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#088-march-2-2017) (more specifically the [Enable HTTP Logging improvement for the OpenStack Terraform provider)](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/12089), the team added OS_DEBUG environmental variable to help provide more information in cases like these. One way to use it is as follows:

```
TF_LOG=DEBUG OS_DEBUG=1 terraform apply ...
```

Once I had this message because I had forgotten to add the ssh key in the OpenStack for the user I was using.

Comment: Thank you! This literally saved my butt. The drive on my flavour was smaller than the image I was trying to put on it. I would have never figured it out without this flag!

Comment: Many Thanks @Ivan! I think this should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your config:

`network { name = "8b510300-610a--9cc3-6e76e33395b4"  }`

You are assigning `name` but providing network `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check all your parameters carefully for typos and/or incorrect values. TF does not do that for you.

This happens when you specify for example non-existent keypair or network name (e.g. n your example, you specified ID instead of name for network).

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify **block_device** block instead of **volume** block.

```
block_device {
    uuid        = "${openstack_blockstorage_volume_v1.myvol.id}"
    source_type = "volume"
}
```

or attach volume directly

```
resource "openstack_compute_volume_attach_v2" "attach_1" {
    instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.basic.id
    volume_id   = openstack_blockstorage_volume_v2.myvol.id
}
```